# Outlook vba calling a stored procedure

Tags: sql, vba, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that runs correctly from a vb application and I have attempted to do the same with a vba Outlook function. This fails when I attempt to read identity of the record created. The sp has the following return.
    Return @@IDENTITY
I use a record set in an attempt to read the value but this fails. The record is created successfully! How would I get this value?

The code Calling the sp:

'The command parameters and the connection are all ok as the record is created!

```
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
  RS.CursorType = adOpenStatic
RS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
RS.LockType = adLockOptimistic
'rs.Open cmd
Set RS = cmd.Execute
If Not RS Is Nothing Then
For Each fld In RS.Fields 'The fields are empty.
    stMessage = stMessage & "| " & fld.Name & " / " & fld.Value & " |"
Next fld
End If
```

Hi The working code is below:

```
Public Function AddNote(ByRef noteID As Integer, ByVal company As Int16, ByVal summary As String, ByVal notetxt As String,
                       ByVal NotesGroup As Integer, ByVal NotesType As Integer)
        Try
            Dim CN As New SqlConnection
            CN.ConnectionString = My.Settings.TDb1
            CN.Open()
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("AddImportedNotes", CN)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyId", company)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", 116)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Summary", summary)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", notetxt)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", DateTime.Now)     
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NotesType", NotesTypeId)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Exported", 0)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExportFile", DBNull.Value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExportDetails", DBNull.Value)
            Dim prm As New SqlParameter("RETURN", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            '  Dim recordId As Integer
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prm)
            prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            noteID = CType(prm.Value, Integer)

            CN.Close()

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
```

[image: results pane in SSMS]

Comment: Might be useful to include your (working) VB code

Comment: I adapted the code in the sp by changing the return to a select but still I am not able to see the result!

Comment: Can you call your adapted sp from a sql client and get a recordset?

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for your reply, yes I can call the sproc from the management studio and get a value. This is a single integer value.

Comment: OK assuming your sp is actually returning a recordset, which part of your VBA is not working?  I'm assuming `RS` is not `Nothing`? Is `RS.EOF` and/or `RS.BOF` true?

Comment: The RS is never open the process completes and when I test RS on the line after execute its closed! as though the client (outlook) is blocking the value for security or some other reason! Do you know if this is a possibility?

Comment: Outlook doesn't do that kind of blocking.  Can you construct a simple test sp which takes no parameters and returns a recordset and get that working via VBA?  Also try checking the `Connection.Errors` collection immediately after calling Execute, to check for anything useful there.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the advice I will try tomorrow morning BST, sorry for the delay I suspect that we are in different time zones.

Comment: Yes we are - PST here...